# Redirect 301 without querystring

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect 301 a url to a new.
Example:

```
http://www.example.com/dir/552-hi.html
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/new.html
```

In the .htaccess i have this code:

```
Redirect 301 /dir/552-hi.html https://www.example.com/new.html
```

And it´s works fine. But it add an querystring like this:

```
https://www.example.com/new.html?id=552
```

I have search a lot here at Stackoverflow and find this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/dir/552-hi.html https://www.example.com/new.html? [L,R=301]
```

But i cant get it to work. Now the redirect does not redirect.
Someone knows what i have to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this in your root directory,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^dir/([\d]+)-hi.html$ new.html?id=$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```